# how to set dynamic image in javascript?

Tags: javascript

```
let stack1=document.querySelector("#stack1");
let randomNumber=Math.floor(Math.random()*52)+1;
stack1.src=`"card1/image_part_0${randomNumber}.jpg"`;

//there are 52 images and their names are in the format 'image_part_0n' where
// n can be any random number from 1 to 52
```

Answer (score 2):

You are doing correct just remove `""` from

```
stack1.src=`"card1/image_part_0${randomNumber}.jpg"`;
```

try it like this

```
stack1.src=`/card1/image_part_0${randomNumber}.jpg`;
```

because of `"` path is getting corrupt.

```js
let stack1=document.querySelector("#stack1");
let randomNumber=Math.floor(Math.random()*52)+1;
stack1.src=`/card1/image_part_0${randomNumber}.jpg`;
console.log(stack1.src);
```

```html
<img id="stack1" src="" alt="picture with dynamic path" width="500" height="600">
```

Comment: i removed the double quote and using just the black tick, still donot working

Comment: @user1724827 have you checked your image folders path with `src=""`
it should be in `YourProjectFolder -> card1 -> image_part_015.jpg` which should look like `YourProjectFolder/card1/image_part_015.jpg`